# Powervault MD circular console cable

Tags: console, hardware, cable, serial

We have two Powervault MD SAS devices, the specific model eludes me as these are remote and not accessible to me and anyone on-site doesn't have the capability to locate a service tag/serial or model number.

I was able to get some pictures in which I see the maintenance console port is some kind of circular serial port for some unknown console cable. Google searching, perusing a variety of Power vault MD manuals, has not been helpful. I'm hoping someone out there is familiar with these older serial console cables and can tell me a name/standard or link to an example. Any/all help in some direction is very much appreciated.

Comment: Here you go: http://discountechnology.com/Dell-CT109-MD1000-3000-3000i-Password-reset-service-cable

Comment: @joeqwerty Looks like you nailed it! Thanks, if you want to make that comment into an answer, I'll gladly accept. Did you just search or have previous knowledge? I'm not sure how I couldn't come up with that.

Comment: We've got an MD3000 so I knew what you were looking for. Answer coming up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MD series does not use a standard cable... they use a PS2 connector with a specific wire setting. If you have a spare PS2 mouse with a serial cable and in need of an urgent solution, then make one yourself:

This is are the pin settings (make one only if you're able to)

```
DB9-------------------PS2

1

2---------------------3 (RXD)

3---------------------4 (TXD)

4---------------------2 (RTS)

5---------------------5,6 (GND)

6

7---------------------2 (RTS)

8

9
```

Comment: Is that right? Any documentation to back that up?

Comment: Ex Dell engineer :) Anyway research in progress for the source

Comment: It is PS2 to serial... http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/storage/f/1216/t/19225592.aspx found it, in forum form! Thanks...awesome emergency solution providing the pin out, very much appreciated!

Comment: Cannot find the source anymore, anyway it's part of my personal KB and dates back at least a couple of years, but I'm sure that it works, it saved my life once

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a password reset/service cable. I found one here:

http://discountechnology.com/Dell-CT109-MD1000-3000-3000i-Password-reset-service-cable

Comment: Is CT109 PS2? Martino's answer has me confused:-) I'm looking into it now. Thanks

Comment: Indeed it is, the cable is a simple DB9-PS2

Comment: The connector on one end is a 6 pin mini-DIN just like a PS2 but I don't believe that it's wired like a PS2.

Comment: I did ask for direction, and I appreciate the link, but I have to accept the pin out answer...I hope you understand. Up voted for your help! CT109 is PS2 to serial, learn something new everyday.

Comment: No worries. Accept the answer that serves you best.